# IF-THEN in canonical form?

Tags: prolog, operator-precedence, canonical-form

defining IF like this :

```
dynamic(if/1).

op(200,  fx, if).
op(150, xfx, then).
op(100, xfy, and).
op(100, xfy, or).
```

generates the following canonical form :

```
?- write_canonical(if x then y).
if(then(x,y))

?- write_canonical(if x and  z then y).
if(then(and(x,z),y))

?- write_canonical(if x and  z or t then y).
if(then(and(x,or(z,t)),y))
```

Is there a way to generate :

```
if( conds, then(actions) ).
```

OR even better :

```
if( conds, (actions) ).
```

like this :

```
if(x,y)
if(x, then(y))
if( and(x,or(z,t)),  then(y))
if( and(x,or(z,t)),  (y))
```

---

one possible alternative I can see :)

```
?- op(200,  xfy, ==>).

?- write_canonical(x ==> y).
 ==>(x,y)

?- write_canonical(x and z ==> y).
 ==>(and(x,z),y)
```

Comment: Did you try defining `if` as a binary operator instead of a unary operator as you currently show it? `if(x, y)`, `if(x, then(y))`, etc, treat `if` as a binary operation.

Comment: just tried.. the same result. of course then :) ?- write_canonical(x if y).
if(x,y)

Answer (score 0):

I found better solution to generate normal clauses. Instead of "then" I can just use ":-"

```
?- write_canonical(if x and z :- y ).
:-(if(and(x,z)),y)

?- assert(if x and z :- write(axz) ).
?- if x and z.
axz
```

Comment: That visually might work, but semantically, it's backwards from normal Prolog. When `:-` is used in the context of `head :- clause_body`, the meaning is *`head` is true **if** `clause_body` succeeds*.